# Selecting top 2 rows of a sorted table for EACH Person ID

Tags: ms-access

I am working on a project with MS Access 2010.

A person with an illness needs to matched against two people without the illness, or controls. These two controls need to be the nearest in terms of age as possible.

I have matched suitable controls but I am struggling to make a query to select just the two controls with nearest dates of birth (Date difference) to the people with the disease.

(The date_difference field is an absolute number so even if they are younger or older the number is always positive - obviously, a higher number indicates they are more years apart).

Can anyone help?

For example... (obviously all names are completely made up!)

[For example...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qKMD.jpg)

I would like the outcome of a query to generate the following:

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Dx8v.jpg)

Any help will be MUCH appreciated!

James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the whole table set-up is imaginary.

```
SELECT b.id,
       b.disease_id,
       b.disease_surname,
       b.control_id,
       b.control_surname,
       b.date_difference
FROM   controls AS b
WHERE  b.id IN (SELECT TOP 2 id
                FROM   controls a
                WHERE  a.disease_id = b.disease_id
                ORDER  BY date_difference)
```

Comment: Of course - all the data is completely made up! -- See my post (obviously all names are completely made up!)

Comment: @user1147976 I meant the table design, not the contents.

Comment: I don't follow. What do you mean?

Comment: @user1147976 The table in "for example", if it is a table, is not normalized.